# Creating an Inclusive List of Id's from Direct/Indirect Relationships Using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following set of direct & indirect Document Dependency relationships (by their type):

[image]

I need to generate an inclusive list of the ENTIRE dependency chain regardless of whether I plug-in..

- The TOP DocumentId or DependencyId
- Any MIDDLE DocumentId or DependencyId
- The BOTTOM DocumentId or DependencyId

**FOR EXAMPLE**

- If I plug-in 18...I should get 18, 16, 20, 22
- If I plug-in 20 or 16...I should get 18, 16, 20, 22
- If I plug-in 22...I should get 18, 16, 20, 22

Keep in-mid other records may exist that I do not want to include:

- See WHITE rows the image below

[image]

I'm not sure posting the code I have is valuable, because it doesnt work.  However, if you want...I will.

**SETUP:**
Below is the code to setup locally...

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Document]    Script Date: 2/13/2018 9:15:57 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Document](
       [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
       [ParentId] [int] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Document] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
       [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[DocumentDependency]    Script Date: 2/13/2018 9:15:57 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DocumentDependency](
       [DocumentId] [int] NOT NULL,
       [DependencyId] [int] NOT NULL,
       [DependencyTypeName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.DocumentDependency] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
       [DocumentId] ASC,
       [DependencyId] ASC,
       [DependencyTypeName] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Document] ([Id], [ParentId]) VALUES (1, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Document] ([Id], [ParentId]) VALUES (2, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Document] ([Id], [ParentId]) VALUES (3, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Document] ([Id], [ParentId]) VALUES (4, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Document] ([Id], [ParentId]) VALUES (5, 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Document] ([Id], [ParentId]) VALUES (6, 5)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Document] ([Id], [ParentId]) VALUES (7, 5)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DocumentDependency] ([DocumentId], [DependencyId], [DependencyTypeName]) VALUES (2, 1, N'DeviceAffinity')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DocumentDependency] ([DocumentId], [DependencyId], [DependencyTypeName]) VALUES (3, 1, N'DeviceAffinity')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DocumentDependency] ([DocumentId], [DependencyId], [DependencyTypeName]) VALUES (5, 4, N'DeviceAffinity')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DocumentDependency] ([DocumentId], [DependencyId], [DependencyTypeName]) VALUES (6, 4, N'DeviceAffinity')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DocumentDependency] ([DocumentId], [DependencyId], [DependencyTypeName]) VALUES (7, 6, N'DeviceAffinity')
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Document]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Document_dbo.Document_ParentId] FOREIGN KEY([ParentId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Document] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Document] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Document_dbo.Document_ParentId]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentDependency]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_DocumentDependency_Document] FOREIGN KEY([DocumentId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Document] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentDependency] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_DocumentDependency_Document]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentDependency]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_DocumentDependency_Document1] FOREIGN KEY([DependencyId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Document] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentDependency] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_DocumentDependency_Document1]
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
DECLARE @Id INT = 7

;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DocumentId) FROM [DocumentDependency]
), 
CTE1 AS (
    SELECT *, RN AS RL FROM CTE 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT T.*, CTE1.RL FROM CTE T 
        INNER JOIN CTE1 ON (CTE1.DependencyId IN ( T.DependencyId, T.DocumentId ) OR CTE1.DocumentId IN ( T.DependencyId, T.DocumentId ) )
        AND T.RN > CTE1.RN
)
, CTE2 AS 
(
    SELECT * FROM CTE1 WHERE RL = 
        (SELECT MIN (RL) FROM CTE1 WHERE DependencyId = @Id or DocumentId = @Id)
)
SELECT DocumentId FROM CTE2
UNION 
SELECT DependencyId FROM CTE2
```

Result for @Id = 7 :

```
DocumentId
-----------
4
5
6
7
```

Retult for @Id = 2:

```
DocumentId
-----------
1
2
3
```

Comment: THANKS MAN...and as Wayne & Garth Once said, "I'm not worthy! I'm not worthy!"

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a recursive CTE to get the fill list.  Here is one method:

```
with cte as (
  select t.documentId, t.dependencyId, t.documentId as top_id
  from t
  where dependencyId is null
  union all
  select t.documentId, t.dependencyId, cte.top_id
  from cte join
       t
       on cte.dependencyId = t.documentId
)
select * from CTE
```

Next, you can look for the id you want:

```
with cte as (
      select t.documentId, t.dependencyId, t.documentId as top_id
      from t
      where dependencyId is null
      union all
      select t.documentId, t.dependencyId, cte.top_id
      from cte join
           t
           on cte.dependencyId = t.documentId
    )
select *
from cte
where cte.top_id = (select cte2.top_id from cte cte2 where cte2.documentId = ?);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this isn't quite working...can you please clarify your answer?

Comment: "not quite working" doesn't really help anyone understand what is going on.

Comment: Sorry,  the solution above includes records that should not be part of the final set.  Please see above